# Using SPLongOperation Within ItemUpdating Event Receiver

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, splongoperation, item-updating

I have an event receiver triggered on `ItemUpdating` that may take some time to run.  The code is as follows:

```
using (SPLongOperation longOperation = new SPLongOperation())
{
    //Custom Messages on the Spinning Wheel Screen
    longOperation.LeadingHTML = "Enumerating ...";
    longOperation.TrailingHTML = "Please wait while the related items are checked.";

    //Start the long operation
    longOperation.Begin();

    foreach (SPListItem someItem in items)
    {

        strNCStatus = ncItem["Status"].ToString();

        if (strStatus != "Closed")
        {
            properties.ErrorMessage = "The Status Of The Item Cannot Be Changed To Closed Because There Are Open Related Items.";
            properties.Status = SPEventReceiverStatus.CancelWithError;
            properties.Cancel = true;
        }
    }

    //End the long operation
    string redirectURL = SPContext.Current.Web.Url;
    longOperation.End(redirectURL);
}
```

You will notice from the code that `SPLongOperation(this.Page)` is not calling the this.Page part.

I want the processing page to display while this operation takes place in the `ItemUpdating`.

I don't have a reference to this.Page because my code is running on `ItemUpdating` event receiver.

Is it valid to use `SPLongOperation` within `ItemUpdating` and if so how can I use `SPLongOperation` without using this.Page as the parameter?

Answer (score 2):

Event Receivers are Asynchronous and they are getting executed in a separate thread.

To make your requirement work, the first thing you need to do it make the event Synchronous. For that you can use the `Sysnchronization` property of the Receiver Definition

```
 ReceiverDefinition.Synchronization=SPEventReceiverSynchronization.Synchronous;
```

Now the `ItemUpdating` will get executed by the same UI thread.

Next issue is how to get the `HTTPContext` object. Solution is to get if from the constructor

```
SPContext spContext;
HttpContext httpContext;

public ReceiverClass () {
    spContext = SPContext.Current;
    httpContext = HttpContext.Current;
}

public override void ItemUpdating(SPItemEventProperties properties) {
    base.ItemUpdating(properties);
    httpContext.Response.Redirect(spContext.Web.ServerRelativeUrl + "/_layouts/longoperationpage.aspx");
}
```

Now in `longoperationpage.aspx` you should do

```
using (var longRunning = new SPLongOperation(Page))
{
   longRunning.Begin();
   // do your long running operation here 
   longRunning.End(null, SPRedirectFlags.Default, Context, null, "window.frameElement.commonModalDialogClose(1, null);");
}
```

Comment: I don't have a longoperationpage.aspx or access to its code.

Comment: Just for the record Before events are synchronous by default so no need to modify ItemUpdating. Only after events are asynchronous by default.

Comment: So does this mean that it is not possible to give feedback to the user in the situation I've described?

Comment: The layout aspx file you should create and then move your long operations to that.

Comment: Seems like a very awkward workaround for something that should be simple - i.e. displaying feedback to the user during an item update that may take a while.

Comment: @motionpotion the purpose of event receiver is not designed to interact with the UI.

Comment: Can you expand in your answer why the longoperationpage.aspx page is required.  And if the ReceiverDefinition.Synchronization needs to be set back to asynchronous after setting it to synchronous.  This answer although helpful, is not detailed enough.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you can't do that as SP Context is not available in Event Receivers and vice versa. The SPLongOperation wouldn't know when the event receiver has finished it's work.